# context.Wait() not preserving parent properties

Tags: json, serialization, botframework

I am creating some dynamic "messages" which can be built and chained together at run-time.

I have the following classes

```
[Serializable]
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Node : INode
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool WaitForInput { get; set; }
    public virtual int OnCompleteID { get; set; }
    public virtual string OnCompleteName { get; set; }
    public virtual Node OnCompleteNode { get; set; }

    public virtual async Task OnExcecute(IDialogContext context, Activity activity)
    {

        if (OnCompleteNode != null)
            if (WaitForInput)
                context.Wait(OnCompleteNode.OnExcecuteAwait);
            else
                await OnCompleteNode.OnExcecute(context, activity);
    }

    public virtual async Task OnExcecuteAwait(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        Activity activity = await result as Activity;

        await OnExcecute(context, activity);
    }
}
```

Which the following class inherits:

```
public class MessageNode : Node
{
    /*public override int ID { get; set; }
    public override string Name { get; set; }
    public override bool WaitForInput { get; set; }
    public override int OnCompleteID { get; set; }
    public override string OnCompleteName { get; set; }
    public override Node OnCompleteNode { get; set; }*/

    public virtual string Message { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
    public virtual string AttachmentLayoutType { get; set; }


    public override async Task OnExcecute(IDialogContext context, Activity activity)
    {
        IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.Text = Message;
        if (Attachments != null)
        {
            reply.Attachments = Attachments;
            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutType;
        }

        await context.PostAsync(reply);

        await base.OnExcecute(context, activity);

    }
}
```

Finally I am building up the data in my RootDialog

```
public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        Schema.MessageNode preMN1 = new Schema.MessageNode();
        preMN1.Message = "and then one more";
        preMN1.ID = 2;
        preMN1.WaitForInput = true;


        Schema.MessageNode preMN = new Schema.MessageNode();
        preMN.Message = "and then";
        preMN.ID = 1;
        preMN.OnCompleteNode = preMN1;
        preMN.WaitForInput = true;

        Schema.MessageNode messageNode = new Schema.MessageNode();
        messageNode.Message = "test";
        messageNode.ID = 0;
        messageNode.OnCompleteNode = preMN;
        messageNode.WaitForInput = true;

        preMN1.OnCompleteNode = messageNode;

        string jTest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageNode);

        context.Wait(messageNode.OnExcecuteAwait);


        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Currently, the OnExcecuteAwait of messageNode gets called first. Which displays "test" in the chat, all good so far. Because the WaitForInput flag is set to true, the next node in the chain (preMN) is called with context.Wait. When the user replies with an input, the text "and then" is sent as desired but rather than moving along to the next node in the chain. It gets stuck at preMN and continues to loop. Upon debugging I discovered that the OnCompleteNode property (along with all virtual properties defined in parent Node class) were cleared.

Strangely, if I override the virtual properties in the MessageNode class the context.Wait breaks completely and the bot continually returns to the RootDialog. 
However if I then remove the line "preMN1.OnCompleteNode = messageNode;" the behaviour works perfectly and the bot ends up at the last node as expected. I imagine this may be due to some loop prevention when the bot state is serialised but ideally I would like to be able to loop back to a previous message if need be.

Comment: This is difficult to follow.  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish?  It looks like you are writing a dialog stack of your own.  Why not use the internal dialog stack?  Also, MessageNode should be [Serializable]

Comment: Sort of. I have a requirement that a dialog can be built by the user at runtime. It was my impression that this goal couldn't be achieved with the internal dialog stack so I came up with a simplified version like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out adding the [Serialized] attribute to the MessageNode class fixed the issue. Thanks for the tip Eric!